# x2go suddenly stopped working

Tags: 18.04, x2go

After server restart, I can not connect to it with x2go anymore, this is x2goclient says to me:

```
NXPROXY - Version 3.5.99.16

Copyright (c) 2001, 2011 NoMachine (http://www.nomachine.com)
Copyright (c) 2008-2014 Oleksandr Shneyder <o.shneyder@phoca-gmbh.de>
Copyright (c) 2014-2016 Ulrich Sibiller <uli42@gmx.de>
Copyright (c) 2014-2016 Mihai Moldovan <ionic@ionic.de>
Copyright (c) 2011-2016 Mike Gabriel <mike.gabriel@das-netzwerkteam.de>
Copyright (c) 2015-2016 Qindel Group (http://www.qindel.com)

NXCOMP, NX protocol compression and NX extensions to this software
are copyright of the aforementioned persons and companies.

Redistribution and use of the present software is allowed according
to terms specified in the file LICENSE.nxcomp which comes in the
source distribution.

All rights reserved.

NOTE: This software has received contributions from various other
contributors, only the core maintainers and supporters are listed as
copyright holders. Please contact us, if you feel you should be listed
as copyright holder, as well.

NX protocol compression is derived from DXPC project.

Copyright (c) 1995,1996 Brian Pane
Copyright (c) 1996,1997 Zachary Vonler and Brian Pane
Copyright (c) 1999 Kevin Vigor and Brian Pane
Copyright (c) 2000,2003 Gian Filippo Pinzari and Brian Pane

All rights reserved.

See https://github.com/ArcticaProject/nx-libs for more information.

Info: Proxy running in server mode with pid '30357'.
Session: Starting session at 'Tue Dec 17 04:31:00 2019'.
Info: Using errors file '/home/stiv/.x2go/S-stiv-50-1576529038_stDMATE_dp24/sessions'.
Info: Using stats file '/home/stiv/.x2go/S-50/stats'.
Loop: WARNING! Overriding auxiliary X11 port with new value '1'.
Warning: Overriding auxiliary X11 port with new value '1'.
Info: Using abstract X11 socket in kernel namespace for accessing DISPLAY=:0.
Info: Connecting to remote host 'localhost:50757'.
Info: Connected to remote proxy on FD#5.
Info: Connection with remote proxy completed.
Loop: WARNING! Unrecognized session type 'unix-kde-depth_24'. Assuming agent session.
Warning: Unrecognized session type 'unix-kde-depth_24'. Assuming agent session.
Info: Using ADSL link parameters 1408/24/1/0.
Info: Using cache parameters 4/4096KB/8192KB/8192KB.
Info: Using pack method '16m-jpeg-9' with session 'unix-kde-depth_24'.
Info: Using ZLIB data compression 1/1/32.
Info: Using ZLIB stream compression 4/4.
Info: No suitable cache file found.
Info: Forwarding X11 connections to display ':0'.
Info: Forwarding auxiliary X11 connections to display ':0'.
Session: Session started at 'Tue Dec 17 04:31:00 2019'.
Warning: Protocol mismatch or no X authentication data.
```

I see no relevant logs in my ~/ folder, any ideas how can I fix this?

Comment: ever find a fix?  trying to setup x2go now with no success

Comment: unfortunately, no

Comment: any suggestions for different solution/software?